# Cannot figure out what is wrong with my code

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I am trying to create a code that will make a new version of a feature class and then geoprocesses some stuff per feature layer. However something in my code is going wrong and I can't figure out for the life of me where it is going wrong. The error that pops up is the following:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Import_Archief_landelijk.py, line 61)
>   Failed to execute.

My knowledge of Python and ArcPy is limited. I work with ArcMap 10.3.1, my code is underneath:

```
import arcpy

import arcpy.mapping

import os



Project_number = "tester"

Regio = "ZN"



arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True



#Hoofdfolders

Hoofdfolder = "U:\ExpImp"

Regiofolder = os.path.join(Hoofdfolder, Regio)

Datafolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, "Base_data")

Archieffolder = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Archief")

Exportfolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, Project_number)

ExportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Export_" + Project_number + ".gdb")

ImportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Import_" + Project_number + ".gdb")



#Vaste waarden voor werkversie aanmaken

inWorkspace = os.path.join(Datafolder, Regio + "@pkgd.sde")

parentVersion = Regio + "_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"



#Vaste waarde voor project layer

ProjectFile = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Project_layer", "Projecten.gdb", "Projecten")



#Vaste waarden om varieerende waarden te bepalen

MXDformat = ".mxd"

MXDName = Project_number + MXDformat

MXDLocation = os.path.join(Exportfolder, MXDName)



#Variereende waarden

Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")

ArchiefName = Project_number + "_" + Date

Archiefsave = os.path.join(Archieffolder, Archiefname)

Mask = os.path.join(ExportGDB, "Mask")



# Execute CreateVersion

arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExpImp_{}".format(Project_number), "PRIVATE")



# Select MXD and start Loop

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDLocation)  # Uses your defined MXD

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes

    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers



        # Any tools you want to run on each layer go here





                        #Parameters defined per layer



                        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr.name)

                        Name = desc.baseName

                        Newname = Name[7:80]

                        Import = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname + "_erase")

                        NewFile = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname)

                        Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged"

                        Versionchange = Regio + "_KGD.ExpImp_" + Project_number





                        #Change to workversion before starting to run tools



                        arcpy.ChangeVersion_management     (lyr.name,

                                                          "TRANSACTIONAL",

                                                          Versionchange)





                        #Run tools on layer



                        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr.name, "INTERSECT", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")

                        arcpy.Erase_analysis (lyr.name, Mask, Import)

                        arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management (lyr.name)

                        arcpy.Append_management(Import, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")

                        arcpy.Append_management(NewFile, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")





# Create folder for Archive documents and manage Project layer

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ProjectFile,"Project_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("Project_lyr", "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")

arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management ("Project_lyr")



arcpy.Copy_management(Exportfolder, Archiefsave)
```

After much needed help and guidelines I adjust the code and cleaned it up a little aswel. I have a bad habit of not cleaning up until after I am done, which causes problems like this. I have chosen to also start using a different python ide (wing) for future coding. The code works now and looks like this:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
import os
import datetime

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Regio = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Hoofdfolders
Hoofdfolder = "U:\ExpImp"
Regiofolder = os.path.join(Hoofdfolder, Regio)
Datafolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, "Base_data")
Archieffolder = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Archief")
Exportfolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, Project_number)
ExportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Export_" + Project_number + ".gdb")
ImportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Import_" + Project_number + ".gdb")

#Vaste waarden voor werkversie aanmaken
inWorkspace = "G:/zn/NM/GGB/Applicaties-Admin/Kerngis/ExpImp/Base_data/ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde"
parentVersion = "ZN_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"
Versionchange = Regio + "_KGD.ExpImp_" + Project_number

#Vaste waarde voor project layer
ProjectFile = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Project_layer", "Projecten.gdb", "Projecten")

#Vaste waarden om varieerende waarden te bepalen
MXDformat = ".mxd"
MXDName = Project_number + MXDformat
MXDLocation = os.path.join(Exportfolder, MXDName)

#Variereende waarden
Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
ArchiefName = Project_number + "_" + Date
Archiefsave = os.path.join(Archieffolder, ArchiefName)
Mask = os.path.join(ExportGDB, "Mask")

# Execute CreateVersion
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExpImp_" + Project_number, "PRIVATE")

# Select MXD and start Loop
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDLocation)  # Uses your defined MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers

      # Any tools you want to run on each layer go here
      #Parameters defined per layer
       desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr.name)
       Name = desc.baseName
       Newname = Name[7:80]
       Import = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname + "_erase")
       NewFile = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname)
       Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged")

       #Change to workversion before starting to run tools
        arcpy.ChangeVersion_management(lyr.name, "TRANSACTIONAL", Versionchange)

       #Run tools on layer
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr.name, "INTERSECT", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
        arcpy.Erase_analysis (lyr.name, Mask, Import)
        arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management (lyr.name)
        arcpy.Append_management(Import, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")
        arcpy.Append_management(NewFile, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")

# Create folder for Archive documents and manage Project layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ProjectFile,"Project_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("Project_lyr", "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management ("Project_lyr")
arcpy.Copy_management(Exportfolder, Archiefsave)
```

Comment: Which line is 61? You have alot of tabs, line breaks etc., can you fix the formatting

Comment: Line 61 appears to be the following: arcpy.ChangeVersion_management(lyr.name, "TRANSACTIONAL", Versionchange)

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis on `Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged"`

Comment: Also, `Hoofdfolder = "U:\ExpImp"` needs to have the proper path formatting: `Hoofdfolder = "U:/ExpImp"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at your code I see four different errors:

1) You wrote:

```py
Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
```

However, you never import `datetime`. Add `import datetime` at the start of your script.

2) You wrote:

```py
ArchiefName = Project_number + "_" + Date
Archiefsave = os.path.join(Archieffolder, Archiefname)
```

However, `Archiefname` is not defined. Change it to `ArchiefName`.

3) The indentation after:

```py
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
```

is messed up. You should have an 8 spaces indented block, not a 24 spaces one.

4) You are missing a right parentheses (`)`) on the line:

```py
Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged"
```

Furthermore, although it does not affect the code execution, I find that leaving so many blank spaces between the lines really difficults your code readability.

Your code could look something like this at the end:

```py
import datetime
import os

import arcpy

Project_number = "tester"
Regio = "ZN"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Hoofdfolders
Hoofdfolder = "U:\ExpImp"
Regiofolder = os.path.join(Hoofdfolder, Regio)
Datafolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, "Base_data")
Archieffolder = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Archief")
Exportfolder = os.path.join(Regiofolder, Project_number)
ExportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Export_" + Project_number + ".gdb")
ImportGDB = os.path.join(Exportfolder, "Import_" + Project_number + ".gdb")

# Vaste waarden voor werkversie aanmaken
inWorkspace = os.path.join(Datafolder, Regio + "@pkgd.sde")
parentVersion = Regio + "_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"

# Vaste waarde voor project layer
ProjectFile = os.path.join(Datafolder, "Project_layer", "Projecten.gdb", "Projecten")

# Vaste waarden om varieerende waarden te bepalen
MXDformat = ".mxd"
MXDName = Project_number + MXDformat
MXDLocation = os.path.join(Exportfolder, MXDName)

# Variereende waarden
Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")  # first error - datetime is not imported
ArchiefName = Project_number + "_" + Date
Archiefsave = os.path.join(Archieffolder, ArchiefName)  # second error - Archiefname to ArchiefName
Mask = os.path.join(ExportGDB, "Mask")

# Execute CreateVersion
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExpImp_{}".format(Project_number), "PRIVATE")

# Select MXD and start Loop
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDLocation)  # Uses your defined MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''):  # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):  # Loop through layers

        # third error - indentation should be 8 spaces, not 24

        # Any tools you want to run on each layer go here

        # Parameters defined per layer
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr.name)
        Name = desc.baseName
        Newname = Name[7:80]
        Import = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname + "_erase")
        NewFile = os.path.join(ImportGDB, Newname)
        Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged")  # fourth error - missing right parentheses
        Versionchange = Regio + "_KGD.ExpImp_" + Project_number

        # Change to workversion before starting to run tools
        arcpy.ChangeVersion_management(lyr.name, "TRANSACTIONAL", Versionchange)

        # Run tools on layer
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr.name, "INTERSECT", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(lyr.name, Mask, Import)
        arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(lyr.name)
        arcpy.Append_management(Import, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")
        arcpy.Append_management(NewFile, lyr.name, "NO_TEST")

# Create folder for Archive documents and manage Project layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ProjectFile, "Project_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Project_lyr", "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", Mask, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("Project_lyr")
arcpy.Copy_management(Exportfolder, Archiefsave)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have alot of unnecessary empty lines, tabs etc. which makes the code difficult to read and debug.

But pasted into any decent python ide you can see for example that the line:

```
Merge = os.path.join(ImportGDB, lyr.name + "_Merged"
```

is missing a ).
[image]